# Midi audio codecs

Tags: 21.04

I'm trying to use a really old computer program that uses midi files for it's background music (through wine). Is there a way to install midi codecs in Ubuntu?

Comment: Windows software via Wine cannot use system's codecs so the point is moot. If you think you need codecs for that software you need to install the Windows versions as well.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: See [this related answer](https://superuser.com/a/1477842).